# Passing a keyvaluepair into a method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a keyvalue pair into a method but am getting a type mismatch regarding the IEnumerable in the method signature.  Am I not initializing the keyvalue pair correctly?

```
  KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "abcdefg"); 

  HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse =   
  PostFormUrlEncoded<HttpResponseMessage> (keyValuePair);


  public static async Task<TResult> PostFormUrlEncoded<TResult>(
                         IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData)
     {
              //calling FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)
     }
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` is a collection of key-value pairs and your `keyValuePair` is a single one. Also please add the code where you are trying to pass something to `PostFormUrlEncoded`.

Comment: Just added the method call

Answer (score 1):

If your method should accept a collection of `KeyValuePair` pairs then use

```
var keyValuePairs = new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "abcdefg") }; 

HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await PostFormUrlEncoded<HttpResponseMessage>(keyValuePairs);
```

if not, then change `PostFormUrlEncoded` method to

```
public static async Task<TResult> PostFormUrlEncoded<TResult>(KeyValuePair<string, string> postData)
```

Comment: It has to accept a collection.  But the method call does not work that way.  It's a mismatch between System.Threading.Task.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> and System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Comment: @John did you add `await`? `await PostFormUrlEncoded<HttpResponseMessage>(keyValuePairs);`

Comment: It isn't an async method.

Comment: It is. See your question: `public static async Task<TResult>` - it means that you declared async method. If it shouldn't then change it to `public static TResult`

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion!   What do I return from that method then? The calling method

Comment: How can I know that? You didn't show the body of that method! And it seems a different question.If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "abcdefg"); 


 public static async Task<TResult> PostFormUrlEncoded<TResult>(
                     KeyValuePair<string, string> postData)
 {
            ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 fixes:

- Add await
- Pass a collection, not a single object
- Rename the Post method to `PostFormUrlEncoded*Async*` - this isn't strictly needed but good practice.

```cs
var keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "abcdefg"); 

HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await // Fix 1
    PostFormUrlEncodedAsync<HttpResponseMessage> (new []{keyValuePair}); // Fixes 2 and 3
```